# Ubuntu uprade 14.04 to 16,01 problems - Lan connection, touch pad,

Tags: networking, touchpad

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and i am stuck.

1. Cant connect to LAN network - able to type password but cant click option for connect (Was able to connect in previous version)
2. Touch pad not working - sometimes right click works

Basically i am completely stuck since these two things are the basic necessity to fix other problems. Now i am able to work with terminal and i tried [fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux) for touchpad, but still not working. While i was trying to do the upgrade the memory wasn't enough i moved some stuffs and managed to upgrade over night. I tried two things - increase partition and reinstall using image, but again with out mouse i can do nothing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.