# Ubuntu touchpad not working

Tags: kernel, touchpad, elantech

I dualbooted ubuntu with windows 10 and my touchpad is not working.

I have tried a few solutions already( [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working) [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working) [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux) [This](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/is-your-laptop-touchpad-not-working.html) ) but all without succes.

**My xinput**

```
↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

If you need any more info let me know in comments!

Greetings Cyber

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: This is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-xenial/+bug/1558489

Comment: A workaround is to switch touchpad settings to "basic" from "advanced".

Comment: @Pilot6 in my bios?

Comment: Sure in yours, not mine ;-)

Comment: I'll try :) i'll report back if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This touchpad is not fully supported by the current Ubuntu, and probably upstream, Linux kernels.

There is a reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-xenial/+bug/1558489) regarding this touchpad.

It will be fixed not before the kernel developers add full support.

As a workaround you can switch the touchpad setting in your BIOS from "Advanced" to "Basic".

You probably won't have all available features, but at least it will work.