# Touchpad disabled for no apparent reason

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, input-devices, xinput

I'm on a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Ubuntu 16.04

My touch-pad suddenly stopped working, I don't know what caused it. I did not tinker with anything related to the touch-pad.

After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux)
I've tried modifying the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** line in the file **/etc/defaut/grub** then running "**sudo update-grub**" and then reeboting but no parameters I enter seem to help. 
.

I also tried adding some lines on this file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf as seen on the third answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux) with no results.

This is the xinput I get.

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

When I run **xinput -test  12** it doesn't track activity (neither trying to move the pointer nor clicking), yet it tracks the activity of other devices just fine.

I really don't like to waste people's time but I don't seem to find any answers online, and since this happened in such a unexpected way I don't know what else to do but ask for help.