# touchpad driver for Asus laptop

Tags: touchpad

I have an Asus ZX50V laptop.  When I installed Ubuntu Studio on it, the built-in mouse pad didn't work.  when I plug in a usb mouse, that works.  Is there a driver available for the touchpad?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command and specify the Ubuntu version.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux might help. If it does record the answer here.