# Acer A515 touchpad not working in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 17.10, elantech

I finally decided to try Ubuntu after testing it with LiveCD. I installed it and everything seemed to work fine but after a while the touchpad stopped working. It was ok but suddenly it just died. The problems remains if i change from Wayland to Xorg. I had installed the synaptic package but nothing change.

This is the information I found about my touchpad:

```
N: Name="ELAN0501:00 04F3:3060 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN0501:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMD0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0501:00/0018:04F3:3060.0001/input/input12
```

It seems that the problem is related to Elantech and multiplexing of the i8092 chip. I found this info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux#764885), but I followed the proposed solution and didn't work. I added either `i8042.reset` or `i8042.kbdreset=1` to the line  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAUL` as suggested.

I'm new in this world so a detailed solution would be really grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours of search I finally found that the problem was a kernel bug so I just upgrade to the latest v4.14 kernel and it solved the issue. The problem was previously solved [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1726934).

If you don't know how to update your kernel just [follow this simple instructions.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ib1Qyf_O_A&t=568s)