# No Right Click Doesn't Work

Tags: touchpad

My laptop is an ASUS model Q524U

I dual booted a laptop to have the option of windows10 and ubuntu 17.10.  the right click in windows10 works, but in ubuntu:

The right click on the mouse pad acts like a left click.
The context menu key does nothing.
Pressing and holding the right button to get a context menu does nothing.

A wireless mouse, does however have both right and left click.

How do I get my mouse pad to right click?

Comment: It appears you are having problems with your laptop's built-in touchpad. To get help, providing the make and model of your laptop would provide essential information.

Comment: My laptop is an ASUS model Q524U

Comment: I suggest you search the site for other Asus touchpad problems, there seem to be a lot of them.  For example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of right click can perhaps be achieved by a two finger tap and that of left click by a one finger tap. I hope this helps. The above feature is in Ubuntu 18.04, although I'm not sure about Ubuntu 17.10, you can try though.