# How can I go about creating a driver to get my touchpad to work?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, laptop, programming

I have an ACER ES 15 laptop, and the touchpad works perfectly fine on Windows but not Ubuntu. I've tried fixing it including checking out the accepted answer here: [Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working). I entered the suggested command `less /proc/bus/input/devices`and I couldn't see my touchpad anywhere, and the person who answered says this means the kernel has no support for it.

So
is there a way I can go about creating a driver to get my touchpad to work? I'm not under any impressions that this is necessarily something easy.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux#764885

Comment: Post #8 here may be helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244174