# Update driver ASUS N550JV for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, asus

I install Ubuntu 18.04 on `ASUS N550JV` and **Touchpad** it does not work properly.

I see `asus.com` and I did not find any updates for Ubuntu

How do I update the touchpad on Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I run `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the current behavior of Touchpad, how is it not working? Please provide more information.

Since your touchpad is Elantech with `id=13`, try running.

```
$ xinput --set-prop 13 "Device Enabled"  0
```

Comment: Hi, I run xinput and update my question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/764885/801564, I run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and multitouch  it does not work properly.

Comment: Did you follow through all steps listed on the mentioned answer or just `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but you need to mention how your touchpad is not working? Is it not registring the right movement? is it erratic? Try searching with those terms so that I can help you further.

Comment: I want to activate `3 fingertouch` and ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`4 fingertouch` (Multitouch), But I do not know what to do. :-(

Comment: I run `xinput --set-prop 13 "Device Enabled"  0` but multitouch has been disabled